# How to retrieve Weblogic's Deployment test points through Weblogic Java API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jmx, wlst

I'm working on a Weblogic health monitoring code base, which is based on JMX. I am trying to get the list of all deployment test points (the `http` addresses, as shown in the following snapshot), and see if that web address is reachable or not.

Is there a way to access the list of these test points in Weblogic's Java API? They are under `[server_name]` --> `deployment` (left menu) --> `[app name]` --> `Testing` pane, under "`Deployment Tests`" table.

[image]

Comment: Not sure this information is available through jmx mbeans exposed by WebLogic. These urls are certainly built dynamically by the console.

Comment: Ummm I see. What are ways to get those?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method call to generate test urls. but from wlst or mbeans you can gather information about server url port and application context. and generate the url.

you can check [Retrieve current server's provider URL at runtime on weblogic (non-deprecated way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32220760/retrieve-current-servers-provider-url-at-runtime-on-weblogic-non-deprecated-wa)

and for wlst you can check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24490/reference.htm#WLSTC119

here is example from my local. how to find out context path
[image]
here how test url looks in weblogic admin
[image]