# How to login to the Weblogic Admin Console in code

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g, wlst

Pages within Weblogic Administration Console (11g) use a REST-like URLs. I would need to access the contents of a specific URL within my Weblogic administration Console in code, for instance like:

```
http://myWLserver.com:10000/console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=DomainConfigGeneralPage&DomainConfigGeneralPortlethandle=com.bea.console.handles.JMXHandle%28%22com.bea%3AName%3DMYPAGE_001%2CType%3DDomain%22%29
```

But before that, I need to login to the console first in my code, similar to what we do in the login page.

How can I authenticate myself and login to the console in Java?

[image]
[image]

Comment: try to send a POST request to /console/j_security_check and send your credentials in j_username and j_password parameters

Comment: usually it is better to use JMX to retrieve information from the servers.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin Thanks. I'm using the POST approach now.

Comment: @devwebcl I was trying JMX, but that only connects to the server (not GUI). Apparently the option I am looking is only available via GUI (not server/`WLST`)

Comment: well, the authenticacion can be done as @emmanuel-collin mentions, in the other hand, what is the information you want to get ?

Comment: @devwebcl list of test points! see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52376715